# svg animation internet explorer

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to make a simple circle animation for a loading for a webpage using svg. It works flawlessly in Google Chrome and in Firefox but does not work in Internet Explorer. The animation does not work and the image is pixelated. How do I fix this?

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  position: fixed;
  width: 210px;
  height: 210px;
}

circle {
  stroke-dasharray: 628.318530718; 
  stroke-dashoffset: 628.318530718;
  animation: 2s draw ease;
  -webkit-animation: 2s draw ease;
  -moz-animation: 2s draw ease;
  -ms-animation: 2s draw ease; 
  -o-animation: 2s draw ease; 
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.logo {
 top: 40%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
 position: fixed;
 height: 320px;
 width: 320px;
 background-image: url("LogoLoading.png");
 background-size: cover;
}

@keyframes draw {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 628.318530718;
    stroke-dashoffset: 628.318530718;
  }
  50% {
    stroke-dasharray: 628.318530718;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 628.318530718;
    stroke-dashoffset: 628.318530718;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes draw {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 628.318530718;
    stroke-dashoffset: 628.318530718;
  }
  50% {
    stroke-dasharray: 628.318530718;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 628.318530718;
    stroke-dashoffset: 628.318530718;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes draw {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 628.318530718;
    stroke-dashoffset: 628.318530718;
  }
  50% {
    stroke-dasharray: 628.318530718;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 628.318530718;
    stroke-dashoffset: 628.318530718;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes draw {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 628.318530718;
    stroke-dashoffset: 628.318530718;
  }
  50% {
    stroke-dasharray: 628.318530718;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 628.318530718;
    stroke-dashoffset: 628.318530718;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes draw {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 628.318530718;
    stroke-dashoffset: 628.318530718;
  }
  50% {
    stroke-dasharray: 628.318530718;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 628.318530718;
    stroke-dashoffset: 628.318530718;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <svg width="210px" height="210px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
 <circle cx="105px" cy="105px" r="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="8px" fill="none" />
    <div class="logo"></div>
 </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: What version of IE are you using? I don't see the image at all unless I change "stroke-dasharray" to `stroke-dasharray: 628.318530718, 0;`

Comment: I am using version 11 of IE. The image displays fine as is on chrome and firefox but is not visible on IE. When I changed my code to: stroke-dasharray: 628.318530718, 0; the image became visible on IE but the animation did not run.